# Update main layout from listview adapter click

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

In my main.xml I have a linearLayout-userinfo which contains a Textview-username. The layout has (VISIBILITY:GONE),  and then a `ListView` below the userinfo layout.

I want to make visible the linearLayout-userinfo when I click a `ImageView` inside the `ListView` and pass username to the textview.

I have the following in my adapter code but doesn't work:

```
img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String owner_username =  ((Map<String, String>)getItem(position)).get("owner_username");
            TextView username     = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userinfo);
            username.setText(owner_username);
            LinearLayout userinfo = (LinearLayout) parent.findViewById(R.id.userinfo);
            userinfo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "ImageView clicked for the row = " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: Im trying to update a textview in my main xml through my custom adapter.  How do I pass my main xml view to the adapter to be able to update the textview

Comment: @AndrewGarcia, kindly post rest of the code, it is hard to make out where are you coding in adapter

Answer (score 0):

Move:

```
final TextView username     = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userinfo);
```

and

```
final LinearLayout userinfo = (LinearLayout) parent.findViewById(R.id.userinfo);
```

before

`img.setOnClickListener[...]`